# Define a struct only if a template is used

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have two templates. They share a commonData struct which might be quite large. Hence I want the struct to be defined only if either or both of the templates are used.
I don't want the commonData struct to be defined inside both of the functions due to it's size. Is this possible?

```
// To be defined only if test1() or test2() is used.
// template <typename cchar> // Error
// #ifdef ...               
struct commonData
{
    char someData[10];
} COMMONDATA;

template <typename cchar>
void test1(cchar* buf)
{
    strcpy(COMMONDATA.someData, buf);
}
template <typename cchar>
void test2(cchar c)
{
    COMMONDATA.someData[0] = c;
}
```

Comment: One option: create a `commonData *cd = nullptr`. Then allocate the memory inside the functions. `if (cd == nullptr) cd = new commonData;`

Comment: Wait, `COMMONDATA` is **not** a `struct`. It's an **object** whose type is a `struct`. With that clarified, the question makes a bit more sense: you don't want to define **that object**, which is quite large, if it isn't going to be used. That distinction, between an object and its type, is important; don't slur over it.

Comment: Exactly Pete! My sense of struct / object and such might be in error. Thank you!

Comment: How large are we talking about? The additional logic may not be worthwhile unless the size of the object is really large.

Comment: @R Sahu: This is not a one-time question. Size is unimportant here

Comment: @Johnny What problem are you trying to solve with not having `COMMONDATA` global object?

Answer (score 2):

If you can, refactor the functions to take a reference to a `commonData`.  Then you can decide exactly when you want to create an object of that type and pass it to either of the functions.

If you want to keep the global variable, then you can use a `std::unique_ptr` as the type of `COMMONDATA` and then initialize it in the template functions like

```
struct commonData
{
    char someData[10];
};

std::unique_ptr<commonData> COMMONDATA;

template <typename cchar>
void test1(cchar* buf)
{
    if (!COMMONDATA)
        COMMONDATA = make_unique<commonData>()
    strcpy(COMMONDATA->someData, buf);
}
template <typename cchar>
void test2(cchar c)
{
    if (!COMMONDATA)
        COMMONDATA = make_unique<commonData>()
    COMMONDATA->someData[0] = c;
}
```

Comment: This somehow reminds me to a singleton. Worth to be noted?

Comment: @Scheff I'm not sure that would help.  AFAIK, the storage for a static object is acquired at program startup, it's just that it doesn't become "alive" until the first pass through the function.

Comment: I thought, a singleton is a one-and-only instance of a class. Before I learnt Meyers singleton trick, I used to implement them similar like your answer - with a global pointer which is accessed by a function and creates the instance on first request. (But I might be wrong.) ;-)

Comment: @NathanOliver: I will try this approach.

Comment: @Scheff It is a one and only instance, the issue is space for that instance will still be allocated even if it is never constructed (I beleive).  If that is the case, then it wont help the OP because the don't want that space consumed unless one of the template functions is actually called.

Answer (score 1):

You can make object `COMMONDATA` a [function static variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) that gets *initialized* on demand.

The space for it is still reserved in [`.bss` section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss), just like in your original code, however, because it is not initialized the hardware memory pages that back the object don't need to mapped into the address space until it gets initialized/written-to (before that the object is backed by the read-only zero page) (provided the object is large enough to occupy one or more memory pages):

```
struct commonData {
    char someData[10];
};

inline commonData& getCOMMONDATA() {
    static commonData COMMONDATA = {};
    return COMMONDATA;
}

template <typename cchar>
void test1(cchar* buf) {
    commonData& COMMONDATA = getCOMMONDATA();
    strcpy(COMMONDATA.someData, buf);
}

template <typename cchar>
void test2(cchar c) {
    commonData& COMMONDATA = getCOMMONDATA();
    COMMONDATA.someData[0] = c;
}
```

---

Since your original code doesn't initialize global/namespace-scoped `COMMONDATA`, it is also stored in `.bss` section, so your original code is even better because it doesn't require `getCOMMONDATA` function at all.

Comment: @Johnny Actually, your original code is as good as this one, you don't need to do anything once you know where the object is stored.

Comment: "once you know where the object is stored". Please elaborate.

Comment: @Johnny The `.bss` section, as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Well, I guess that's assembler programming. I began with machine code but today it's C / C++ only so .bss is lost on me.

Comment: @Johnny It is important to know in which region of memory an object is stored in your system. There are typically `.text` for code, `.data` and `.bss` for globals objects, stack for locals and heap for dynamically allocated.

Comment: I'm aware of that. How do I a) find out where? and more important b) benefit from that knowledge in my C++ code?

Comment: @Johnny  What particular problem are you trying to solve with not having global object `COMMONDATA`?

Comment: Never said it can't be global. On the contrary. Please read the question again

Comment: @Johnny I risk repeating myself: what problem are you trying to solve with not having to define `COMMONDATA` global object?

Comment: COMMONDATA is huge and i don't want it defined if it is not going to be used. As previously explained ...

Comment: @Johnny But what is the _problem_? Does it crash, take too long to start,...?

Comment: @Johnny _quite large_ is not a problem. I still have hope in you. How does your problem manifest itself?